# AG Grid: Row becomes un-editable after trying to edit twice

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an ag grid that populates data dynamically. I have enabled full-row editing.
I am facing this issue where, when I double-click on any column the row becomes editable, and then I click outside without doing any edit. I repeat this once more. After this when I try to double-click again the row becomes uneditable. Can anyone help me with this?
[AG Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owoy5.png)

```
  gridOptions: GridOptions = {
    getRowId: (params: GetRowIdParams): string => {
      return params.data.rowId;
    },
    getRowStyle: params => {
      if (params.data === undefined) {
        return { opacity: 0 };
      }
      return {};
    },
    defaultColDef: {
      flex: 1,
      resizable: true,
      editable: true
    },
    editType: 'fullRow',
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    tooltipShowDelay: 0,
    stopEditingWhenCellsLoseFocus: true,
    onSelectionChanged: this.onSelectionChanged
  };

  columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      headerName: '',
      checkboxSelection: true,
      headerCheckboxSelection: true,
      maxWidth: 50,
      editable: false,
    },
    {
      headerName: this.translateService.translate("proposalDetails-eventDetails-columnHeader-startDate", "Start Date"),
      editable: true,
      field: '',
      cellEditor: GridDateCellEditorComponent,
      valueGetter: params => {
        return params.data.startDate;
      },
      valueSetter: params => {
        if (params.newValue == "Invalid date")
          params.newValue = "";
        params.data.startDate = params.newValue;
        return true;
      }
    }
];
```

```
<ag-grid-angular #eventDetails id="df-eventDetailsGrid-expandable" class="df-table ag-theme-alpine"
            [overlayNoRowsTemplate]="noRowsTemplate" [rowData]="rowData" [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
            [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [postSortRows]="postSortRows" (cellKeyPress)="launchToggleWithEnter($event)"
            (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)" [frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents">
        </ag-grid-angular>
```

**Steps to recreate:**

1. Double-clicked to make the row editable.
2. Click outside the grid or on the next row to stop editing.
3. Repeat the above steps once more.
4. The third try row becomes uneditable. **Expected** row to become editable. **Actually resulted** -> Row became uneditable.

Comment: Without any code posted I think you won't get the help you need.

Comment: @MishaMashina I have added some code.